# Form freezes when opened for second time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, wcf

I am developing a Windows Forms application that access a WCF service. I ran into a great problem that I can't predict the reason of it. Even the Visual Studio debugger not showing any exception in the Output view. The scenario is like this, I have a custom user control that has a `linkLabel` on it. Whenever the link label is clicked, a form is opened and a class object is passed to it. The class definition of this object resides on WCF service on a remote server. Now the problem is that when I click the `linkLabel`, the form opens perfectly loading each of its component according to the class object passed to it. But when I close this form and click that `linkLabel` again, the form opens but immediately freezes after loading some elements. I tried many code variations. Edited many part of code that I think can affect. But none of them showed the difference. Since, I don't know where actually is the code has error, I am posting the `linkLabel` click code and functions that are called after it is clicked.

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
      Enabled = false;
      string temp = Title.Text;
      Title.Text = "Opening...";
      System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(openTopic));
      t.Start();

      Title.Text = temp;
      Enabled = true;
}

void createTopicWindow()
{
      TopicViewer t = new TopicViewer(t);
      Invoke(new Action(() => t.Show()));
}
private void openTopic()
{
      Invoke(new Action(() => createTopicWindow()));
}
```

The above is the edited code, since I was getting `Cross thread exception` before.

Following is the code of constructor of the form that is called when clicked the `linkLabel`:

```
 try
 {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.t = topic;
        if (IsHandleCreated == false)
            CreateHandle();
        System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(loadTopic));
        th.Start();
        Common.openedTopics.Add(this);
        AddComment addComment1 = new AddComment();
        addComment1.Topic = t;
        addComment1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panel5.Controls.Add(addComment1);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  { }

void loadTopic()
{

     Invoke(new Action(()=>tHead = new TopicHeader()));
     Global.SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(tHead,"Topic", t);
     Global.SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(tHead,"Dock", DockStyle.Fill);
     Invoke(new Action(()=>panel1.Controls.Add(tHead)));
     Global.SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(this,"Text", t.Title + " - Topic Viewer");
     if (t.Description.Trim().Length > 0)
     {
         Global.SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(webBrowser1, "DocumentText", t.Description);
     }
     else
     {
         Invoke(new Action(() => tabControl1.TabPages[0].Dispose()));
     }

     Global.SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(tabPage2, "Text", "Comments (" + client.getComCount(t.TopicID) + ") ");

 }
```

TopicHeader is another small user control.
Please anyone tell me the solution to this?

Comment: Why are you doing this:   catch (Exception)  { }    You are hiding problems.

Comment: Missing the LoadTopic

Comment: Whats the reason to create the form via a thread on the gui thread?

Comment: @SteveWellens: It doesn't matter to `throw` an exception in catch block, because the output view of Visual Studio will show exception if it occurs. But its not doing that.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: Because the other form loads value from the remote server and that may take time depending on users speed. So I don't want to freeze the main form on which this thread is created. Its just to improve user experience.

Comment: But the form is still on the same thread created? If a form needs to populate data which could take a long time, you should handle that async in the child form. This way you make childforms dependend on parent forms. If the child has a 'problem' the parent shoudn't fix it. :)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen See my updated code with loadTopic(). And I can provide you this much code only. And did you mean to say that I should call the form using Async functions? I am not sure but does it will work as I wanted?

Comment: Look at my example, it's an easy way to execute longrunning code on a thread and update the form again on the gui thread.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva - "Visual Studio will show exception if it occurs"  It's still a bad practice because you might forget about it.  And, VS may be setup to break only on unhandled exceptions.  Your code 'handles' the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .Net 4.5, then using [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) would be easiest solution. That way, you don't need any `Invoke`s

```
async private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(LongRunningTask, 
                                                 TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    this.Text = s;
}

string LongRunningTask()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    return "------";
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem is not the long running task. As I mentioned its loading fine and fast for the first time. But when I click the `linkLabel` for the second time, it freezes.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva How about changing your code a little bit and testing this approach? Since you don't deal with threads, invokes etc, it reduces the chance of a bug.

Comment: ok I will try it and will tell you after sometime coz I have to change many parts of my code to implement your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @I4V, my problem is solved. My problem was something else and I solved it somehow but your code gave a speed boost to my app so marking your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give a direct answer to you question, but this may give a hold on.

```
public void Form_Load()
{
    // do some stuff on the gui-thread



    // i need to do something that takes a long time:
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
    {
        // i'll execute it on the ThreadPool
        // Long running code....




        // update results in mainform on gui thread.
        Invoke(new Action( delegate
        {
            // because the invoke will execute this on the gui-thread, you'll able to update controls.

            // update my gui controls.             
            DataGrid.Source = myReceiveDataThing;
        }));
    }
}
```

You might expand the code, to check if the form is still valid.

Comment: Actually the problem is not the long running task. As I mentioned its loading fine and fast for the first time. But when I click the `linkLabel` for the second time, it freezes.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen this helped me learn something new about thread and thread pools. :) +1 to you